# Split R dataframe into several rows

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I am looking for a way to split my dataframe into several rows.

My test input data looks like this

```
   data <- read.table(text ="group;  yr1; yr2; val; col2
    a;  1927;   1934;   -140; coltest
    a;  1953;   1955;   -480; coltest
    b;  1957;   1958;   -280; coltest1
    b;  1961;   1965;   -1420; coltest1 ", sep=";", header=T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I am looking for is a way to calculate the value of each year and write it out in a row like this:

```
group; yr1;    yr2;   val;   col2
    a; 1927; 1928;    -20;   coltest 
    a; 1928; 1929;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1929; 1930;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1930; 1931;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1931; 1932;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1932; 1933;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1933; 1934;    -20;   coltest
    a; 1953; 1954;   -240;   coltest
    a; 1954; 1955;   -240;   coltest
    b; 1957; 1958;   -280;   coltest1
    b; 1961; 1962;   -355;   coltest1
    b; 1962; 1963;   -355;   coltest1
    b; 1963; 1964;   -355;   coltest1
    b; 1964; 1965;   -355;   coltest1
```

I am able to calculate each value for a year like this but am unable to split it into separate rows.

```
data$new <- data$val/(data$yr2-data$yr1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility using `expandRows` from my "splitstackshape" package along with a few compound statements with "data.table":

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(
  as.data.table(
    data, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, diff := yr2 - yr1][, 
      val := val/diff], "diff")[, yr1 := yr1 + sequence(.N) - 1L, 
        by = list(group, rn)][, yr2 := yr1 + 1][]
#     rn group  yr1  yr2  val
#  1:  1     a 1927 1928  -20
#  2:  1     a 1928 1929  -20
#  3:  1     a 1929 1930  -20
#  4:  1     a 1930 1931  -20
#  5:  1     a 1931 1932  -20
#  6:  1     a 1932 1933  -20
#  7:  1     a 1933 1934  -20
#  8:  2     a 1953 1954 -240
#  9:  2     a 1954 1955 -240
# 10:  3     b 1957 1958 -280
# 11:  4     b 1961 1962 -355
# 12:  4     b 1962 1963 -355
# 13:  4     b 1963 1964 -355
# 14:  4     b 1964 1965 -355
```

---

In comparison to @beginneR's approach, this is much more efficient, but the pure "data.table" approach is even faster.

Here's a comparison on just 1000 rows:

The functions....

```
beginneR <- function() {
  data %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    do(data.frame(group = .$group, 
                  yr1 = .$yr1:(.$yr2-1), 
                  yr2 = (.$yr1+1):.$yr2, 
                  val = .$val/(.$yr2 - .$yr1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

ananda <- function() {
  expandRows(
    as.data.table(
      data, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, diff := yr2 - yr1][,
        val := val/diff], "diff")[, yr1 := yr1 + sequence(.N) - 1L, 
          by = list(group, rn)][, yr2 := yr1 + 1][]
}

codoremifa <- function() {
  as.data.table(data)[,SNO := .I][, 
    val := val / (yr2 - yr1)][,
      list(yr = yr1:(yr2-1), val), by = list(group,SNO)][,
        SNO := NULL][, yr2 := yr + 1][]
}
```

The timings....

```
data <- do.call(rbind, replicate(250, data, FALSE))
dim(data)
# [1] 1000    4
system.time(beginneR())
# |====================================|100% ~0 s remaining
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.408   0.000   2.297 
system.time(ananda())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.017 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ananda(), codoremifa())
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#      ananda() 16.791794 17.048305 18.096050 17.786861 18.537067 22.34243   100
#  codoremifa()  8.018706  8.201175  8.649698  8.406204  8.649132 13.87685   100
```

Comment: thank you. but I get an error `could not find function "expandRows"`. I am on MacOs X 10.8.5 and using R.3.1.1. I installed the package with the command `install.packages("splitstackshape")`

Comment: I am not getting it to work. I run splitstacks package version 1.2.0 and data.table 1.9.2 and reinstalled both packages from source.

Comment: Nice answer, especially with the comparison (as expected..) (+1)

Comment: yes, thanks for the information. I have just seen the requirements for data.table in the CRAN documentation and it seems that it isn't possible to install version 1.9.4 on Snow Leopard. I will change to Windows and try it there!

Comment: I got it to work without any problems under Windows 7. Thank you!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, now you'll have to update your `expandRows` function with the more efficient version ;) (just kidding)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have one question left: I am trying to figure out how to keep another row in the final result and filling up the resulting gaps. I added a new column col2 to my sample data in order to illustrate it.

Comment: @nebuloso, I assume you mean "how to keep another column in the final result". My approach handles that automatically, and for Codoremifa's answer, simply add the new column name to the line that looks like `list(yr = yr1:(yr2-1), val)` (that is, change it to `list(yr = yr1:(yr2-1), val, col2)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,SNO := .I]
data[,val := val / (yr2 - yr1)]
(data[,
     list(yr = yr1:(yr2-1), val),
     by = list(group,SNO)
     ][,
       SNO := NULL
       ][,
         yr2 := yr + 1]

)
```

Output

```
#     group   yr  val  yr2
#  1:     a 1927  -20 1928
#  2:     a 1928  -20 1929
#  3:     a 1929  -20 1930
#  4:     a 1930  -20 1931
#  5:     a 1931  -20 1932
#  6:     a 1932  -20 1933
#  7:     a 1933  -20 1934
#  8:     a 1953 -240 1954
#  9:     a 1954 -240 1955
# 10:     b 1957 -280 1958
# 11:     b 1961 -355 1962
# 12:     b 1962 -355 1963
# 13:     b 1963 -355 1964
# 14:     b 1964 -355 1965
```

Comment: this is not entirely correct, it adds one row too much at the end of each group!

Comment: @nebuloso, that's an easy fix. Just changing `yr1:yr2` to `yr1:(yr2-1)` should do it.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, would be interesting to see this one included in your benchmark

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but it produces the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   do(data.frame(group = .$group, 
                 yr1 = .$yr1:(.$yr2-1L), 
                 yr2 = (.$yr1+1L):.$yr2, 
                 val = .$val/(.$yr2 - .$yr1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

#Source: local data frame [14 x 4]
#Groups: <by row>
#
#   group  yr1  yr2  val
#1      a 1927 1928  -20
#2      a 1928 1929  -20
#3      a 1929 1930  -20
#4      a 1930 1931  -20
#5      a 1931 1932  -20
#6      a 1932 1933  -20
#7      a 1933 1934  -20
#8      a 1953 1954 -240
#9      a 1954 1955 -240
#10     b 1957 1958 -280
#11     b 1961 1962 -355
#12     b 1962 1963 -355
#13     b 1963 1964 -355
#14     b 1964 1965 -355
```